# Can't change destination for bootable Windows 10 USB in Boot Camp Assistant

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb, boot-camp

My Windows 10 computer is plagued with a blue screen upon boot that claims I'm missing a winload.exe file. So, I'm trying to create a bootable USB with my Mac's Boot Camp Assistant with the Windows 10 ISO I downloaded from Microsoft, but I don't ever see a screen allowing me to set the destination. Boot Camp Assistant automatically sets the destination to my Mac's hard drive and won't allow any changes.

[image: Boot Camp Assistant screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Boot Camp is designed to put Windows on your Mac, not create bootable USBs for PCs. If you keep on with the process [& have a new-enough Mac & BC6], then it will eventually make a bootable key. You will then have to use BC again to remove the newly created volume. Backups are essential. Old Macs & BC<6 will not make USB keys

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin. I guess I'll have to find another way to revive my PC.